# Render rdlc to pdf in azure website

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, azure, reporting-services

I get the following error when trying to export a localreport .rdlc to PDF on azure.

> Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException: An error
>   occurred during local report processing. --->
>   System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.    at
>   System.Drawing.Graphics.GetHdc()

I know this is a known issue and is related to GDI see this [Windows Azure forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/b4a6eb43-0013-435f-9d11-00ee26a8d017/report-viewer-error-on-export-pdf-or-excel-from-azure-web-sites)

Anyway does anyone know anyway around this issue. I thought exporting to html or something but local reports only seem to give 3 options pdf, excel or word. I know I could use SQL Reporting service but need to use this as a local report.

Answer (score 9):

This is a very old question. This is functioning today, but not on the free/shared-hosting platform. You have to scale it up to **Basic** or **Standard**, then you are actually using your own Virtual Machine. It is lot more expensive but you can host more sites on that VM.

Switching is easy, just move the selector in **Scale > Web Hosting Plan Mode**

Comment: I was having the same issue and I solved scaling up the App Service plan

Answer (score -1):

It have no idea of Windows Azure, but since this question was anskend a year ago I will try to help you. I got the same exception when I wanted to make a simple rdlc report and this tutorial helped me: http://softwarekaffee.blogspot.ro/2013/03/how-to-create-report-rdlc-in-wpf.html .

Hope it helps!